# Plotly Bar chart in R (with specific colour for each of the bars)

Tags: r, colors, plotly, bar-chart

A similar kind of question (but in python version) to the question I would like to ask is given in the following hyperlink:
[Plotly: How to manually assign bar colors to categorical lables in go.bar()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72531577/plotly-how-to-manually-assign-bar-colors-to-categorical-lables-in-go-bar)

So basically my question is how do I always assign a specific colour to my bars no matter if or not that bar category has value or is 0. For example, if I always want the Supportive bar green, the Neutral bar yellow and the Resistant bar red, how do I achieve that? In both the following 2 data frames, dfA and dfB, I would like the colouring scheme of the categories to be as stated above (i.e., "Supportive" - Green, "Neutral" - Yellow, and "Resistant" - Red ):

```
categories<-c('Supportive', 'Neutral', 'Resistant') 
vals <- c(40, 25, 35)
categoriesB<-c('Supportive', 'Neutral', 'Resistant') 
valsB <- c(40, 0, 35)
dfA <- data.frame(categories, vals)
dfB <- data.frame(categoriesB, valsB)
```

It is very important that even in dfB's case the colour of the bars to stay consistent with the colour of bars in dfA. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: You should be able to just supply a naked vector of colors to the `colors` argument to create an unambiguous mapping of colors to categorical variables.

Comment: @DanAdams thanks for your comment. Would appreciate if you can answer in detail, providing R script to back that up. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a fixed mapping of a categorical variable to a color (in `plot_ly` or otherwise) it's best create a named vector of colors so the relationship is unambiguous and preserved even if some of the values of the categorical variable are missing.

In `plot_ly` you assign the name of the categorical variable to `color` and then provide the colormap you want to use with the `colors` argument.

Also it's often better to convert categorical variables to `factor`s in R so they give more predictable behavior in various ways.

```r
library(plotly)

# set categories as factor to enforce order in plot
d <- data.frame(categories = factor(c('Supportive', 'Neutral', 'Resistant'), 
                                    levels = c('Supportive', 'Neutral', 'Resistant')),
                vals = c(40, 25, 35))

# create fixed color mapping
colormap <- setNames(object = c("green", "yellow", "red"),
                     nm = d$categories)

# assign color to categories variable and provide colormap to colors
plot_ly(data = d,
        x = ~categories,
        y = ~vals,
        type = "bar",
        color = ~categories,
        colors = colormap)
```

[image]

Now you will always preserve the relationship of color to `Categories` even if some are missing or the order changes.

```r
# color mapping preserved even with missing levels
plot_ly(data = d[-1,],
        x = ~categories,
        y = ~vals,
        type = "bar",
        color = ~categories,
        colors = colormap)
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

```
library(tidyverse)
library(plotly)

categories = c('Supportive', 'Neutral', 'Resistant') 
vals = c(40, 25, 35)

categoriesB = c('Supportive', 'Neutral', 'Resistant') 
valsB = c(40, 0, 35)

dfA = data.frame(categories, vals)
dfB = data.frame(categoriesB, valsB)

fig = plot_ly(data = dfA, 
              x = ~categories, 
              y = ~vals, 
              type = "bar",
              name = c('Supportive', 'Resistant', 'Neutral'),
              marker = list(color = c('#FF0000', '#FFFF00', '#00FF00')))  %>% 
  layout(title = "Categories Chart")
fig

fig1 = plot_ly(data = dfB, 
              x = ~categoriesB, 
              y = ~valsB, 
              type = "bar",
              name = c('Supportive', 'Resistant', 'Neutral'),
              marker = list(color = c('#FF0000', '#FFFF00', '#00FF00')))  %>% 
  layout(title = "Categories Chart")
fig1
```

[image: Sample Output dfA]
[image: Sample Output dfB]

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I don't see the colours matching the ones stated in colour_map, i.e, "Supportive"  is not  Green, "Neutral" is not Yellow, and "Resistant"  is not Red in your answer. The colouring is imperative to appear like stated in the question. Any idea how to fix that?

Comment: I have updated the script. Let mw know if it works for you!